# Set Formula to be the cell of Range (Eg A1) vs contents of A1

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I'm trying to setup a Macro which inserts some text infront of the cell next to it's contents. The problem is the code is copying the contents of the cell next to it, but then I can't drag the formula down to continue it. I want the formula to end in A1, not the contents of A1 which are 1111. Eg, the formula is normally `="ADDTOFRONT"&A1` but it now `="ADDTOFRONT"&1111`

Eg:
[image]

```
'''''PUBLICVARS'''''
Public cll As Variant
Public clloffset As Variant

'''''ENDPUBVARS'''''
'''''MAINSUB'''''
Public Sub Add_BINWH()

cll = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Which Cell To Add Formula? Eg: B1", Default:="B1")
Set clloffset = Range(cll).Offset(0, -1)
ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range(cll).Formula = "=" & Chr(34) & "ADDTOFRONT" & Chr(34) & "&" & clloffset.Value

End Sub
'''''ENDMAINSUB'''''
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want the address put in the string not the value.

> `clloffset.Value`

Should be

```
clloffset.Address(0,0)
```

Comment: Yup, boy I had a hard time searching/explaining that. Set the value of the range to the cell not the cells value...… Thanks!

Comment: Was the question well asked, if so consider up-voting. I'm not here for rep, but it seems everybody only votes on answers!